# Starting Illustrator causes panels on second monitor to be scaled down to thumbnail size

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, adobe-illustrator, illustrator-cs6

I have an iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2012) running El Capitan with an extra monitor.
I set Illustrator's Workspace in a way that my main screen opens in the main iMac monitor and all the panels open in the external monitor (a Samsung, not sure if matters.) Both screens have the same size and resolution.

Every time when I start Illustrator the panels on the external monitor are scaled down really small, it looks like a thumbnail in the top part of the screen. Clicking on it has no effect.
The only way to restore function is to open Spaces and select the Desktop that contains the panels, then everything works fine. Check my screenshot attached.

Is that a bug, and is there a way to fix it?

[image: ![2 monitors, Illustrator panels on the left]